# Why might be file copying on Windows Explorer much slower than Command Prompt

Tags: windows, performance, windows-explorer, file-transfer

When I copy a file in command prompt, it occurs instantly.

But when I copy a file inside Explorer of Windows 7, it waits around 3-10 seconds before starting the copying process.

Also the icons of the files in Explorer appear very slowly. Maybe this is related.

Since copying in command prompt occurs instantly, the problem has to be related to the Explorer. What might be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The GUI is slower because of all the background processes related to the GUI (displaying prompts, estimating time remaining, visual effects) that don't occur within command line. It usually has nothing to do with the action that is occurring, the copying is taking the same amount of time, but the GUI processes are slowing down the complete action as a whole