# Why is a shut down performed faster when initiated from the command line?

Tags: windows, shell, ubuntu, command-line

Whenever i use a command like

```
shutdown -s -f -t 00
```

I can see that the shutdown occurs faster than when I go and click the shutdown button in the Windows GUI.

This scenario can be compared with my other OS, i.e. Ubuntu as well. In ubuntu terminal, if I enter the following command for shutdown, the process occurs quite faster and never failed to my knowledge. But if I use the shutdown button in the GUI, the system sometimes hangs and its process takes longer to execute.

```
sudo init 0
```

I can sense that the terminals and the command prompt works directly on the kernel. But I am curious to know whether there are any other technical stuff going on behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Firstly***, the commands you're using aren't the same commands that are used when you press the GUI button, so there's some speed in using those commands alone.

***Secondly***, the GUI has GUI-specific prompts/effects/etc that it must run through before it can get to the command. This will also add time to the overall effect of clicking the button in the GUI.
This isn't a bad question, it's not as cut and dry as say [command copy vs GUI copy](https://superuser.com/questions/386483/why-might-be-file-copying-on-windows-explorer-much-slower-than-command-prompt/386491#386491), but I think the main performance gain is in the actual commands that you're using (e.g. limited wait time, forcing close). The GUI will have a default wait time and will prompt for force close, the *prompting* falls into category **2** while the *forcing* falls into category **1**.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, when you use the GUI shutdown, the system waits for closing all running programs, up to 20 seconds. Maybe when you use the command, Windows doesn't wait for it. (Perhaps the same on Linux?)

Comment: Even When i run the command, the running programs are closed and only then it proceeds with the shutdown process... So, if you have any answer can you please elaborate in technical means...